# which is the efficient way to store a tree structure data in file and read that using java code

Tags: java, file, data-structures, tree

Currently i am working on an application which has data as tree. For example :- 
A server has a list of clusters(C1, C2, C3, C4 ... ).

Each cluster has n number of applications (A1, A2, A3, A4 .....).

Each application has a list of modules (M1, M2, ......).

Every module can contain n number of services.

I want to store the data into a text file so that user will be able to modify it manually. Which would be the efficient way to store the data into file? also, how can i read that data using java program into efficient way?

Comment: "I want to store the data into a text file so that user will be able to modify it manually". Please clarify this. When you talk about a 'way to store data', are you concerned about file placement?

Comment: The file will be kept on the server. In which format should i keep the data so reading the file and parsing into an Object would be easier?